# Updating VS Code in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, extension, visual-studio-code

I want to update my VS Code so tried multiple option in doing so all result in something like this

`sudo dpkg -i code_1.45.1-1589445302_amd64.deb`

[image]

```
martin@martin:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install code
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
code is already the newest version (1.45.1-1589445302).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

[image]

But when i check in the VS Code about I see.

[image]

I needed to upgrade my VS Code because some extensions doesnt activate. The reason I think is because VS Code is not latest.

[image]

No matter how many times I reload them they dont activate

UPDATE:

```
martin@martin:~$ umake --list-installed 
visual-studio-code: Visual Studio focused on modern web and cloud
    path: /home/martin/.local/share/umake/ide/visual-studio-code

martin@martin:~$ snap list | grep -i code
martin@martin:~$ flatpak list | grep -i code
martin@martin:~$
```

Comment: I have added the out put they look the same like that @N0rbert they say `code is already the newest version (1.45.1-1589445302).
`

Comment: @N0rbert il get other output

Comment: i tried searching it in ubunt software its not there @N0rbert

Comment: I'm again asking about the output of exact `which code` command. Also add `umake --list-installed` , `snap list | grep -i code` , `flatpak list | grep -i code ` .

Comment: @N0rbert i added them result. I added an image of command and their result also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to stay with deb-packaged version - remove the umake version:

```
umake --remove ide visual-studio-code
```

And use deb-package instead.

---

But personally I would recommend to use Visual Studio Code from `umake ide visual-studio-code` and remove it from APT with `sudo apt-get remove code` .

Comment: i will try this one out

Comment: `Version: 1.45.1` works perfectly. My wish is to have a brain like yours. Thank you

Comment: one last thing can you explain why the way i did it is not working and why this one works?

Comment: You have had two VSCodes installed is same time - one from `umake` and one from deb-package. Their locations were declared in $PATH variable with priority of `umake`'s path.

Answer (score 0):

If you had installed VS Code from downloading .deb package earlier, it will not update unless you have added vscode repository.

Add VS Code repository by executing following commands in terminal.

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
```

Update packages list.

```
sudo apt update
```

It will show you, incase any new versions available of vscode. 
You can upgrade to latest available vscode.

```
sudo apt install code
```

Comment: why is it when i search it on ubuntu softwares its not there

Comment: Because it is not in ubuntu repository.

Comment: tried your solution still when i look at the about in the IDE itself its still 1.25

Comment: i tried to purge it and reinstall earlier but I still get the same IDE I mean the folder I last opened is still there. Its like purge failed.

Comment: Please add steps you performed and error you got in question.

Comment: I purge code then autoremove for unused things from purge then install using [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Answer (score 0):

Install the Visual Studio Code snap package from Ubuntu Software, and it will be updated automatically.

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```